# BigQuery SQL: Conditionally Count Column Values (if exactly 2/3 codes exist from list) While Grouping By Unique ID

Tags: sql, group-by, google-bigquery, count, conditional-statements

Let's say I have the following sample input table:

```
| ID   | Code |
|------|------|
| 1234 | 121A |
| 1234 | 334B |
| 1234 | 543A |
| 1112 | 121A |
| 1112 | 333B |
| 2234 | 121A |
| 2234 | 301B |
| 3314 | 121A |
```

I want to create a new column called "Count". The "Count" column gets a 1 value if and only if across the entire table the unique ID meets the following conditions:

- must have 121A in the "Code" column
- **can only have 1 of the following two codes: 333B, 334B** in addition to 121A

Note that if the unique ID has 121A and one of the two codes listed above and another code (not of the two) then that's fine as well.

Otherwise the ID gets a "Count" value of 0.

Given the rules above, my desired output table is below:

| ID | Code |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | 1 |
| 1112 | 1 |
| 2234 | 0 |
| 3314 | 0 |

I know how to do this in Python but am not as familiar with SQL, especially BigQuery SQL.  How do I write this query using BigQuery SQL?

Comment: You've done a good job of describing your data and the problem, but you have not shown us whether you have attempted a solution, so it feels like you are using Stack Overflow as a free code-writing service.  Show us what you've tried and you'll probably get more responses.

Comment: Hint: Use `group by id` and start with `SELECT id,  if( countif(code="121A")>0 and ((countif(code="333B") + countif(code="334B") < 2)) 1,0) from tbl group by 1`.

Comment: @Samuel Your code hint helped me figure it out using a slightly different array of countifs ... thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you would want conditional aggregation, something like:

```sql
SELECT
  ID,
  CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN Code = '121A' THEN 1 END) = 1
        AND COUNT(CASE WHEN Code IN ('333B', '334B ') THEN 1 END) = 1
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END AS Code
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY
  ID;
```

The above code requires that the group satisfies each of the conditions exactly once, not more. If that is not your intention then please be clear.

Answer (score 1):

See example

```
select *
  ,case when c121A=1 then
     case when c333b=1 and c334b in(0,1) then 1
          when c334b=1 and c333b in(0,1) then 1
     else 0
     end
   else 0
   end isCode
from(
select *
  ,sum(case when code='121A' then 1 else 0 end)over(partition by id) c121A
  ,sum(case when code='333B' then 1 else 0 end)over(partition by id) c333B
  ,sum(case when code='334B' then 1 else 0 end)over(partition by id) c334B
from test
  )x
```

Several possible cases in output

| id | code | c121a | c333b | c334b | isCode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1112 | 121A | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1112 | 333B | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1234 | 543A | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1234 | 121A | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1234 | 334B | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 2234 | 121A | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2234 | 301B | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3314 | 121A | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 4414 | 121A | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 4414 | 333B | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 4414 | 334B | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 4515 | 333B | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 4516 | 334B | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 4517 | 121A | 1 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 4517 | 333B | 1 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 4517 | 333B | 1 | 2 | 0 | 0 |

Or

```
select *
  ,case when c121A=1 then
     case when c333b=1 and c334b in(0,1) then 1
          when c334b=1 and c333b in(0,1) then 1
     else 0
     end
   else 0
   end isCode
from(
select id
  ,sum(case when code='121A' then 1 else 0 end) c121A
  ,sum(case when code='333B' then 1 else 0 end) c333B
  ,sum(case when code='334B' then 1 else 0 end) c334B
from test
group by id
  )x
```

| id | c121a | c333b | c334b | isCode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1112 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2234 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1234 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 4515 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 4516 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 3314 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 4414 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 4517 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 0 |